# Ubuntu 20.04: Terminal equivalent of setting mouse speed via settings

Tags: mouse, settings

The slider in settings for Ubuntu 20.04 changes my mouse speed but I'd like to have the equivalent in a terminal command.
Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to change the mouse speed via terminal, ignore the Windows part as the actual question is terminal equivalent of what gnome settings is doing with the slider. For context, Windows goes from 0 - 11, often times people have theirs set to 6/11 ~= .55 which is the value I'd like my mouse speed to be at.